# android keyboard: on input form click page scrolls down, on click outside scrolls up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have made a website where scrolling is blocked and the only way to navigate is through buttons which go to #id sections. on desktop everything works fine yet on mobile devices i have 2 errors which i looked all night and haven't found an answer.

1. on android on input click scrolls down, then goes up, i need to
   know how to keep this input fixed there so page won't move.
2. on iphone scrolling is working for some reason, even though on
   any other device its not and PLAY BUTTON is disabled dont know why

8 hours of research tried every possible way to prevent.default from input, tried `onfocusout="scrolldown100vh"` so it will get me back to the form but .. nothing works.

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var currScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
  document.body.scrollTop = calc(~"currScroll + 100vh");
});
// this code also gives me this error in console:Uncaught ReferenceError: calc is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, height=device-height">

<input type="text" id="tetext" style="background-color: black;">
```

Every #id is set to width 100% and height 100vh.

- on input text click > scrolls down about 100vh i think.
- outside of input click > scrolls up way looks like 150vh from click, which

this is happening due to the android keyboard.

basicly i want that when i click the input, keyboard should obviously appear but should not move my webpage up or down.

**edit**: did a little more testing so:
on #section 3 i have a 1 line input.
on #section 4 i have a contact form with 3 inputs.

1. section3 input is in the middle of the page (top 50%).
   When i click it and keyboard appears, it goes exactly 100vh down to section 4. When i remove the keyboard it goes back up 150vh !
2. if i go to section4 contact form and click the input, being on the very bottom, it stays put, however when i remove the button, it goes UP EXACTLY in the same spot section3 input sends me after removing keyboard

   3. HOWEVER, when i open an input and it scrolls down, after i start typing on thek eyboard, it starts scrolling up until it reaches the input, but after keyuboard dissapears again it scrolls top 100vh

**edit2** !IMPORTANT:
I've done several other tests on different mobile devices and the results are very different, for example in zte blade normal browser everything functions correctly, on huawei chrome and ie i get the scrolling issue.. mozilla firefox is a disaster :)